# Fluent Validations. Inherit validation classes

Tags: c#-4.0, fluentvalidation

I used Fluent Validator. But sometimes I need create a hierarchy of rules. For example:

```
[Validator(typeof(UserValidation))]
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

public class UserValidation : AbstractValidator<UserViewModel>
{
    public UserValidation()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();

        this.RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class RootViewModel : UserViewModel
{
    public string MiddleName;       
}
```

I want to inherit validation rules from UserValidation to RootValidation. But this code didn't work:

```
public class RootViewModelValidation:UserValidation<RootViewModel>
{
    public RootViewModelValidation()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.MiddleName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.MiddleName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

How can I inherit validation class using FluentValidation?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To resolve this, you must change `UserValidation` class to generic. See code below.

```
public class UserValidation<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : UserViewModel
{
    public UserValidation()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();

        this.RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty();
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(UserValidation<UserViewModel>))]
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

public class RootViewModelValidation : UserValidation<RootViewModel>
{
    public RootViewModelValidation()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.MiddleName).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(x => x.MiddleName).NotEmpty();
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(RootViewModelValidation))]
public class RootViewModel : UserViewModel
{
    public string MiddleName;
}
```

Comment: I would personally try to make UserValidation abstract. But it's already great like that! Thank you!